# {!Action} not merging in Text email template when joining Salesforce Community

Tags: apex, community, email-template, customer-community, user

I have an `email template` which is type `Text` and it is configured to send when a new community user joins.

**Text Email Template**

```
Dear {!Receiving_User.FirstName},

To log into your account, please use the username below:

Username: {!Receiving_User.Username}

Please click on the link below to set your password and access your account:

URL: {!Action}
```

The name and username merge, but the `{!Action}` does **not**.

**Email Output**

> Dear Tim Berners-Lee,
>
> To log into your account, please use the username below:
>
> Username: tim@internet.com
>
> Please click on the link below to set your password and access your
>   account:
>
> URL:

I have tried creating the portal using via UI using the `Enable Customer User` button on the `Person Account` page layout, and I've tried creating the `User` using Apex, and in both cases  `{!Action}` does not merge.

**Questions**

1. What am I doing wrong
2. How can I get `{!Action}` to merge correctly?